# document.querySelector('.class'); vs jQuery $(.class); - are they interchangeable?

Tags: jquery

### Research:

After searching it would seem that jQuery's `$('.class')` is equivalent to `document.querySelector('.class')` so am a bit confused in this situation.

---

### Problem:

1. Replacing this:

   ```
   var expander = document.querySelector('.expander');
   ```
2. With this jQuery:

   ```
   var expander = $('.expander');
   ```
3. Causes this:

   ```
   if( (expander.offsetHeight < expander.scrollHeight) || (expander.offsetWidth < expander.scrollWidth)) {
       // .expander has overflow
   }
   else {
       // .expander doesn't have overflow
   }
   ```

To always evaluate as false.

Just to be clear, I'm trying to use the jQuery syntax - `document.querySelector` is currently being used and works fine.

---

### Questions:

Is there a jQuery equivalent to `document.querySelector` that will work in this instance?

Or is there something unique about this situation that causes `$('.class-name');` to not work?

---

### Full context:

jsFiddle (comment in line 3 of js): http://jsfiddle.net/cmscss/3xbvxcav/1/

```
var expander = $('.expander')
    expanderContracted = document.querySelector('.expander-contracted');

// check if there's overflowed text inside the expander
if( (expanderContracted.offsetHeight < expanderContracted.scrollHeight) || (expanderContracted.offsetWidth < expanderContracted.scrollWidth)) {
    expander.find('a.expander-expand-link[href="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.expand = !this.expand;
        $(this).html(this.expand?"Less <i class='fa fa-caret-up'></i>":"More <i class='fa fa-caret-down'></i>");
        $(this).closest('.expander').find('.expander-contracted, .expander-expanded').toggleClass('expander-contracted expander-expanded');
    });
}
else {
    expander.find('a.expander-expand-link[href="#"]').hide();
}
```

Comment: `querySelector` should work, but note that it only gets the first element with that class in the DOM

Comment: did you link jquery in your html?

Comment: `querySelectorAll()`

Comment: @adeneo querySelector works perfectly even with multiple elements - I'm having the issue when I switch to jQuery

Comment: @indubitablee Yes, jQuery is linked and working

Comment: Not quite, a simple console log of the 2 values will show quite a difference. Mainly that `document.querySelector()` returns an *element object* and jQuery returns a *jQuery object*. If you want to access the normal element  object with jQuery you'll have to do `$('.expander')[0].scrollHeight`

Comment: @CMSCSS http://jsfiddle.net/3xbvxcav/  Just check it, you are wrong. Anyway, adeneo is always correct, IIRC...

Comment: Oh, okay, you're using a jQuery object with native methods, jQuery doesn't have `scrollHeight` properties etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not the same only because `.querySelector` always return 1 or 0 HTML node, jQuery return all of them. `$('.expander-contracted')` will be the same as `document.querySelectorAll('.expander-contracted')` (minus the fact that jQuery return a jQuery object).

That being said, that's not the problem. What actually happen is that jQuery return a jQuery object that has its own method and property. `document.querySelector` return an HTML element which also have its own property and method that are not the same as the jQuery object.

Since `.offsetHeight` and other properties in the condition are all HTML element properties, you can't directly access it with a jQuery object. jQuery has its own method to access those properties : [`.prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

So, instead of :

```
expanderContracted.offsetHeight;
```

use :

```
expanderContracted.prop('offsetHeight');
```

Of course, you'll have to change every properties that are not jQuery related (I've used `offsetHeight` has example).

Comment: Cheers mate, thanks for your help much appreciated: http://jsfiddle.net/cmscss/3xbvxcav/2/

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this i believe this will work....**

```
// check if there's overflowed text inside the expander
if( ( $('.expander-contracted')[0].offsetHeight <  $('.expander-contracted')[0].scrollHeight) || ( $('.expander-contracted')[0].offsetWidth <  $('.expander-contracted')[0].scrollWidth)) {
    $('.expander')[0].find('a.expander-expand-link[href="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.expand = !this.expand;
        $(this).html(this.expand?"Less <i class='fa fa-caret-up'></i>":"More <i class='fa fa-caret-down'></i>");
        $(this).closest('.expander').find('.expander-contracted, .expander-expanded').toggleClass('expander-contracted expander-expanded');
    });
}
else {
    $('.expander')[0].find('a.expander-expand-link[href="#"]').hide();
}
```

Comment: what did you change other than `$('.expander-contracted');`? even if you change that, OP said `$('.expander')` wasnt working so carrying the jQuery selector throughout the code isnt an answer in this case...

Comment: @indubitablee correct, I've pasted it in but this answer doesn't work - it's what I've already been trying (I think).